# Qual a melhor maneira de criar uma constraint de chave estrangeira condicional?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira, chave-composta

Em alguns casos, é interessante criar uma referência de chave estrangeira **condicional**, ou seja, que não permite referenciar todas os registro de outra tabela, mas apenas aqueles que assumem uma condição.

Por exemplo: Se você possui uma tabela **pessoas** que armazena tanto clientes como fornecedores (aceita "C" ou "F" na coluna "tipo_pessoa"). Imagine uma tabela de vendas só poderia referenciar pessoas que são clientes, mas não fornecedores. Qual a melhor maneira de criar essa restrição?

Uma possível maneira (não sei se a melhor) seria criar uma coluna adicional e uma referência composta, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  accepts_comments BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (id, accepts_comments)
);

CREATE TABLE comments(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  text VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  accepts_comments BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT (true) CHECK (accepts_comments = true),
  FOREIGN KEY (post_id, accepts_comments) REFERENCES posts (id, accepts_comments)
);

INSERT INTO posts (id, title, accepts_comments) VALUES (1, 'aceita', true);
INSERT INTO posts (id, title, accepts_comments) VALUES (2, 'não aceita', false);


-- a parte interessante

-- ok
INSERT INTO comments (id, post_id, text)
VALUES (1, 1, 'aceita');

-- erro de chave estrangeira violada
INSERT INTO comments (id, post_id, text)
VALUES (2, 2, 'não aceita');

-- erro da constraint check
INSERT INTO comments (id, post_id, text, accepts_comments)
VALUES (3, 2, 'não aceita valor diferente', false);
```

O objetivo é impedir comentários em posts marcados para não permiti-los.

Esse é o jeito certo de fazer isso, ou há uma maneira mais elegante?

Answer (score 4):

Isto aqui:

```
UNIQUE (id, accepts_comments)
```

Não se faz necessário. Já existe a verificação da chave primária (que já garante que o registro é único).

Isto aqui:

```
accepts_comments BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT (true) CHECK (accepts_comments = true)
```

Também não faz muito sentido, visto que a tabela só vai aceitar `accepts_comments` com o valor `true`, e não com qualquer outro, o que deveria ser o caso pra fazer sentido de essa coluna existir.

Entendo que a intenção foi aproveitar a chave estrangeira:

```
FOREIGN KEY (post_id, accepts_comments) REFERENCES posts (id, accepts_comments)
```

Mas não é a maneira correta de fazer. A informação `accepts_comments` só precisa existir em `posts`. Você está criando uma redundância de dados apenas pra usar a funcionalidade do impedimento da inserção pela chave estrangeira que, a meu ver, é uma gambiarra.

A maneira correta é:

## 1. Impeça inserção direta na tabela

```
DENY INSERT ON dbo.comments TO PUBLIC
```

## 2. Crie uma *Stored Procedure* que realize essa inserção, conferindo se o *post* aceita comentários

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.InsertComment
 @PostID INT,
 @Text VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO comments (post_id, text)
 SELECT p.id, @Text
 FROM posts p
 WHERE p.id = PostID
 AND accepts_comments = true

END
GO
```

## 3. Dê `GRANT` apenas para a `Stored Procedure`

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.InsertComment TO PUBLIC
```

Estou supondo que seu schema irá ficar assim:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  accepts_comments BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE comments(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  post_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  text VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  accepts_comments BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT (true),
  FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts (id)
);
```

Comment: E se utilizar uma procedure para inserção não for viável? Se eu utilizar um ORM, por exemplo. Gostaria de ter acesso direto à tabela, mas com a restrição funcionando de alguma maneira. Porém entendo que sua proposta é viável se eu escrever todo o SQL na unha.

Comment: Aí você levanta uma `trigger` de inserção que faça a mesma verificação que a `procedure` faz. Precisa do código?

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma neste caso seria uma TRIGGER de validação verificando se na condição requerida a coluna atende a regra em questão. Eu todavia reveria o modelo pois pode se tratar de um problema de modelagem.