# CONSTRAINT que adiciona parametro à FOREIGN KEY?

Tags: sql-server, constraint

Tenho o seguinte código para a criação de tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE pessoa (
cod_pessoa int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
nm_pessoa varchar (50) NOT NULL,
tp_pessoa char(1) NOT NULL,
endereco_pessoa varchar(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pessoa_tipo CHECK (tp_pessoa = 'F' or tp_pessoa = 'J')
);

CREATE TABLE pessoa_fisica (
cod_pessoaf int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
cpf int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
FOREIGN KEY(cod_pessoaf) REFERENCES pessoa(cod_pessoa)
);

CREATE TABLE pessoa_juridica (
cod_pessoaj int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
cnpj int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
FOREIGN KEY(cod_pessoaj) REFERENCES pessoa(cod_pessoa)
);
```

O meu problema esta nas tabelas `pessoa_fisica` e `pessoa_juridica`. Como puderam ver a tabela `pessoa` tem um campo que indica seu tipo `tp_pessoa` (F para física e J para jurídica), gostaria de adicionar uma `CONSTRAINT` ou algo do tipo nas tabelas `pessoa_fisica` e `pessoa_juridica` que delimite as foreign keys somente para o tipo correto de pessoa. Ex (código entre **):

```
CREATE TABLE pessoa_fisica (
cod_pessoaf int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
cpf int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
FOREIGN KEY(cod_pessoaf) REFERENCES pessoa(cod_pessoa) **WHERE pessoa.tp_pessoa = 'F'**
);
```

Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Uma `CHECK CONSTRAINT` seria suficiente?

Comment: @GuilhermePortela Até poderia mas como ela deve ser criada? Não tenho como usar uma subquery dentro de uma constraint, tenho? Ou referenciar colunas de outras tabelas? Acho que deve ser algo na própria constraint foreign key ou um check aplicado a ela, mas como?

Comment: @MarianaSempe Não sei se estas tabelas são apenas para exemplificar a necessidade. Em sendo uma necessidade real, eu resolveria com outra modelagem que dispensasse esse tipo de constraint.

Comment: @Caffé essa é a necessidade real! Como você sugere?

Comment: @MarianaSempe Considerando só estes campos, você pode simplesmente sumir com as tabelas `pessoa_fisica` e `pessoa_juridica` e adicionar um campo `cpf_cnpj` em `pessoa`; seria o correto porque CPF e CNPJ são de fato o mesmo tipo de informação (identificação única nacional de uma pessoa). Se os demais campos destas duas tabelas forem `rg` e `inscricao_estadual`, ainda não justifica a complexidade das novas tabelas. Veja que algumas empresas são isentas de inscr.estadual e algumas pessoas usam outra identificação que não RG; estes docs são apenas atributos e não parte da identidade de uma pessoa.

Comment: @MarianaSempe Se houver muito mais campos exclusivos para `pessoa_fisica` ou `pessoa_juridica`, informe na sua pergunta que ajudará a sugerir uma modelagem.

Comment: @Caffé poderiam ter vários (este é um trabalho), o problema é que preciso mostrar normalização (aqui a 2FN) por isso das duas tabelas. Coloquei somente cpf/cnpj para simplificar o cadastro depois.

Comment: @MarianaSempe Entendo... Resolver um problema que de fato não existe é mais difícil. É difícil normalizar pessoa porque ela é muito simples. Talvez você possa escolher uma entidade mais fácil de normalizar, e o mais fácil para exercitar normalização é com entidades complexas. Um "cliente", por exemplo, poderia ter categoria, tipo de relacionamento, % permitido de comprometimento de renda... E alguns destes atributos podem estar relacionados de modo a dar origem a novas tabelas, facilitando a demonstração da normalização.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como não sei a estrutura da sua aplicação e não sei as permissões de banco de dados e quem vai ter acesso, para fazer o que você precisa eu faria assim:

#### Function para a constraint

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ValidaPessoa (@id integer, @tipo varchar(1))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @retorno int;
  select @retorno = count(*) from pessoa where cod_pessoa = @id and tp_pessoa = @tipo;
  RETURN(@retorno);
end;
```

#### Constraint

```
alter table pessoa_fisica add constraint pessoa_fisica_ck check (dbo.ValidaPessoa(cod_pessoaf, 'F') = 1)

alter table pessoa_juridica add constraint pessoa_fisica_ck check (dbo.ValidaPessoa(cod_pessoaj, 'J') = 1)
```

#### Explicação

Ao tentar salvar o registro, o sistema irá pegar o valor de `cod_pessoaj` e/ou `cod_pessoaf`e vai chamar a função criada, fazendo o SQL e retornando o erro se não estiver com o cadastro certo.

Desta forma você consegue garantir que insert diretos no banco de dados, também sejam validados. Na minha opinião a store procedure, somente aumenta a complexidade de algo simples e pode ser burlada facilmente.

Comment: +1 O bacana desta solução é que mantém simétrica a inserção de registros em vez de inserirmos ora por *INSERT* em algumas tabelas e ora por *stored procedure* em outras. Eu só não acho que seja mais difícil de burlar do que a Stored Procedure. E onde você foi buscar esse nome *ValidaUsuario*? :D

Comment: @Caffé Agora que vi que fumei legal escrevendo ValidaUsuario. Editado.

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma maneira usando chave estrangeira, mas [nesta resposta explico porque isso não é uma boa ideia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41398/qual-a-melhor-maneira-de-criar-uma-constraint-de-chave-estrangeira-condicional/41402#41402).

O correto, como dito na mesma resposta, é você impedir manipulação direta dos dados pelos usuários do banco, e criar *Stored Procedures* que façam essa conferência pra você.

Há, ainda, uma alternativa usando *Triggers*, mas por experiência não recomendo por causa dos falsos positivos (principalmente envolvendo vários registros inseridos ou atualizados ao mesmo tempo) e pelo desempenho, que cai muito.

Na prática:

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.InserirPessoaFisica
 @CodPessoa INT,
 @Cpf INT
AS
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO pessoa_fisica (cod_pessoaf, cpf)
 SELECT p.cod_pessoa, @Cpf
 FROM pessoa p
 WHERE p.cod_pessoa = @CodPessoa
 AND p.tp_pessoa = 'F'

END
GO

Create PROCEDURE dbo.AtualizarPessoaFisica
 @CodPessoa INT,
 @Cpf INT
AS
BEGIN

 UPDATE pessoa_fisica
 SET cpf = @Cpf
 FROM pessoa p
 WHERE p.cod_pessoa = @CodPessoa
 AND p.cod_pessoa = pessoa_fisica.cod_pessoaf
 AND p.tp_pessoa = 'F'

END
GO
```